# How do I align the price and add-to-cart button horizontally on a woocommerce single product page?

Tags: html, css, horizontal-alignment

I'd like them to appear beside each other rather than one above the other.

See the example below: https://tefllessons.com/product/present-perfect-lesson-duration/

I tried display:inline-block but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex` is great for this and `justify-content` and `align-items` can be used to align content depending on flow and direction

apply these to the container element of the items

EDIT:

you'll get the desired effect by wrapping the price and the form element that contains the button inside a div and applying display: flex to that div.

also in your case I applied the margin-bottom from the button to said div, you will need to remove the margin from the button. and added a gap property to set some spacing between flex items.

css:
after grouping, just add this class to said div

```
.flex-align-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 1.3em;
    gap: 1.5rem;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's not working for me. Here is the page I'm looking to align the 'BUY' button and price on.  https://tefllessons.com/product/present-perfect-continuous-2/ Sorry, I'm trying to teach myself how to make these changes with no coding experience.

Comment: no worries, we've all been there :) I adjusted my answere for your pecific instance

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to but it's not working for me. Can you share the code you used to wrap the price and the form element? sorry!

Comment: I did, if you look at the first screenshot, you'll see that `<p class="price" >` and the form 'cart' element are inside the `<div class="flex-align-center" >` element.. that is how your Html should look/be structured.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I can't seem to get it to work but I'm thinking it might be neater if the price is displayed inside the add-to-cart button. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: simply add the price text to the 'buy' text inside your button. the how depends on how you get and then display variable data i.e if youre using a framework like react or vue. or aa cms like wordpress